# Derivation of "activity coefficient form of the Gibbs-Duhem equation"

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I'm trying to differentiate the excess Gibbs energy ($G^{ex}$) to get the activity coefficient ($\gamma_k$), which writes:

$$
\frac{\partial (G^{ex}/RT)}{\partial n_k} = \ln\gamma_k \quad (1)
$$

in the process of deriving the above equation, I saw some conditions are used, like:

$$
RT\sum_i n_i \left( \frac{\partial (\ln \gamma_i)}{\partial n_k} \right)_{T,P,n_{i\neq k}} = 0 \quad (2)
$$

- $n_i$: mole numbers

or

$$
x_1 \text{d} \ln \gamma_1 + x_2 \text{d} \ln \gamma_2 = 0 \quad (3)
$$

- $x_i$ mole fractions

**I'm wondering how (2) and (3) are derived?** I saw they were mentiond as "activity coefficient form of the Gibbs-Duhem equation"

but how Gibbs-Duhem equation

$$
\sum_i n_i \text{d} \mu_i = 0
$$

becomes (2) or (3) are unclear to me.

**References:**

- (1) and (2) from *Thermodynamics and Its Applications by Tester and Modell*, P357-358
- （3）from Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%E2%80%93Duhem_equation)

Answer (score 1):

Remarks:

- Equation (1) is by **definition** the natural logarithm of the activity coefficient, so you cannot derive it
  $$ \left[\frac{\partial (nG^\text{E})}{\partial n_j}\right]_{p,T,n_{k \neq j}}
     \equiv RT\ln(\gamma_j) $$
- Equation (2) is **false**, we will check it out later.
- Equation (3) can be **derived**.

I will show you how to derive the Gibbs-Duhem equation and attack at the end the second point.

---

We postulate that the thermodynamic property $nM$ can be expressed as a total differential in terms of the pressure $p$, temperature $T$, and all amounts $n_1, n_2, ...$
\begin{equation}
  \mathrm{d}(nM) =
  \left[\frac{\partial (nM)}{\partial p}\right]_{T,n} \mathrm{d}p +
  \left[\frac{\partial (nM)}{\partial T}\right]_{p,n} \mathrm{d}T +
  \sum_i \left[\frac{\partial (nM)}{\partial n_i}\right]_{p,T,n_{j \neq i}}
  \mathrm{d}n_i \tag{2}
\end{equation}
here $n$ loosely means all the amounts, and the thermodynamic property $M$ is written per total amount, e.g., $\pu{J mol^-1}$. Even though we can choose any thermodynamic variables, these ones are only convenient for the Gibbs energy, but you can select any of them.

The last partial derivative, by **definition**, is the partial molar property $\overline{M}_i$ of species $i$ in a solution
\begin{equation}
  \mathrm{d}(nM) =
  n\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial p}\right)_{T,n} \mathrm{d}p +
  n\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial T}\right)_{p,n} \mathrm{d}T +
  \sum_i \overline{M}_i \mathrm{d}n_i \tag{3}
\end{equation}
where we also took out $n$ from the first two partial derivatives. Now we do two things: (1) open up the differential $\mathrm{d}(nM)$, and (2) use that $n_i = x_i n$ or $\mathrm{d}n_i = n\mathrm{d}x_i + x_i\mathrm{d}n$ (with these transformations, now our variables are in terms of molar fractions rather than amounts, so we change the indexes of the partial derivatives)
\begin{align}
  n\mathrm{d}M + M\mathrm{d}n &=
  n\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial p}\right)_{T,x} \mathrm{d}p +
  n\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial T}\right)_{p,x} \mathrm{d}T +
  \sum_i \overline{M}_i (n\mathrm{d}x_i + x_i\mathrm{d}n) \\
  \color{blue}{n\mathrm{d}M} +
  \color{red}{M\mathrm{d}n} &=
  \color{blue}{n\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial p}\right)_{T,x} \mathrm{d}p} +
  \color{blue}{n\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial T}\right)_{p,x} \mathrm{d}T} +
  \color{blue}{n\sum_i \overline{M}_i \mathrm{d}x_i} + 
  \color{red}{\sum_i x_i\overline{M}_i \mathrm{d}n} \\
  \left(M - \sum_i x_i\overline{M}_i \right)\mathrm{d}n &+
  \left[\mathrm{d}M -
  \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial p}\right)_{T,x} \mathrm{d}p -
  \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial T}\right)_{p,x} \mathrm{d}T -
  \sum_i \overline{M}_i \mathrm{d}x_i\right] n =0 \tag{4} \\
\end{align}
Eq. (4) gives us two conditions for it to hold.

**1. Summability relation** The first one is the famous **summability relation**. It connect the property of the *whole* solution $M$ to the partial molar properties of *all* the species. We wil manipulate this one a little bit
\begin{align}
  M  &= \sum_i x_i\overline{M}_i  \tag{differentiate} \\
  dM &= \sum_i \overline{M}_i \mathrm{d}x_i +
        \sum_i x_i \mathrm{d}\overline{M}_i \tag{5}
\end{align}

**2. G-D Equation** The second one is the famous Gibbs-Duhem, once we combine it with Eq. (5)
\begin{align}
  \require{cancel}
  \mathrm{d}M -
  \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial p}\right)_{T,x} \mathrm{d}p -
  \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial T}\right)_{p,x} \mathrm{d}T -
  \sum_i \overline{M}_i\mathrm{d}x_i &= 0 \\
  \cancel{\sum_i \overline{M}_i \mathrm{d}x_i} +
  \sum_i x_i \mathrm{d}\overline{M}_i +
  \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial p}\right)_{T,x} \mathrm{d}p -
  \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial T}\right)_{p,x} \mathrm{d}T -
  \cancel{\sum_i \overline{M}_i\mathrm{d}x_i}  &= 0 \\
  \sum_i x_i \mathrm{d}\overline{M}_i =
  \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial p}\right)_{T,x} \mathrm{d}p -
  \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial T}\right)_{p,x} \mathrm{d}T& \tag{7}
\end{align}
Eq. (7) is general for any change in pressure, temperature, and amounts. For the case where the pressure $p$ and temperature $T$ are held constant, we have your Eq. (3) (if we divide by $n$), because the property $M$ is the Gibbs energy and its partial molar property is named the chemical potential $\overline{G}_i = \mu_i$
$$ \boxed{\sum_i x_i \mathrm{d}\mu_i = 0} \tag{8} $$

---

An easy way to prove that eq. (2) is wrong, is to test it in an activity model. For example, do the summation
$$ \sum_i n_i \left(\frac{\partial \ln \gamma_i}{\partial n_i}\right)_
   {p,T,n_{k \neq i}} \color{blue}{\neq} \tag{9} 0 $$
under the Margules $1$ parameter activity model, where
$$ \ln(\gamma_1) = \frac{A}{RT} x_2^2 \quad 
   \ln(\gamma_2) = \frac{A}{RT} x_1^2 \tag{10,11} $$
and prove, in a beautiful manner, that you get instead $-(2A/RT)x_1x_2$.

I let you prove that if you manipulate your Eq. (2) a bit, you can obtain the summability relation. Try it over Eqs. (10) and (11), so you can recover the excess Gibbs energy for the Margules $1$ parameter model, which is $G^\text{E} = Ax_1x_2$.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, I was trying to derive equation (2)(or3) from the Gibbs-Duhem equation. But if we change the direction, to replace activity coefficient with chemical potential, things will be easier.

### Details

According to the **Gibbs-Duhem equation**, that the chemical potential of one component of a mixture cannot change independently of the chemical potentials of the other components. Thus:

$$
      \begin{align*}
        \sum_i n_i \text{d} {\mu_i} = 0
      \end{align*}
$$
Also, the defination of activity coefficient is:
$$
\begin{align*}
    \ln \gamma_i = \frac{\mu_i -\mu_i^{id}}{RT}
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align*}
    \sum_i n_i \left[ \frac{\partial \ln \gamma_i}{\partial n_k} \right]_{T,P,n_{i \neq k}} &=
    \sum_i n_i \left[ \frac{\partial (\mu_i - \mu_i^{id})}{\partial n_k} \right]_{T,P,n_{i \neq k}} \\
    &= \sum_i n_i \left[ \frac{\partial \mu_i}{\partial n_k} - \frac{\partial \mu_i^{id}}{\partial n_k}\right]_{T,P,n_{i \neq k}} \\
    &= \sum_i n_i  \left[ \frac{\partial \mu_i}{\partial n_k} \right]_{T,P,n_{i \neq k}}- \sum_i n_i \left[ \frac{\partial \mu_i^{id}}{\partial n_k}\right]_{T,P,n_{i \neq k}} \\
\end{align*}
$$
recall the Gibbs-Duhem equation $\sum_i n_i \text{d} \mu_i = 0$, therefore:
$$
\begin{align*}
    \sum_i n_i  \left[ \frac{\partial \mu_i}{\partial n_k} \right]_{T,P,n_{i \neq k}} &=0 \\
    \sum_i n_i \left[ \frac{\partial \mu_i^{id}}{\partial n_k}\right]_{T,P,n_{i \neq k}} &=0
\end{align*}
$$
so we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_i n_i \left[ \frac{\partial \ln \gamma_i}{\partial n_k} \right]_{T,P,n_{i \neq k}} =0
\end{align*}
$$